# TFS lab test run aborted: "The start date ... cannot occur after the end date ..."

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2012 to run lab tests. Recently, we are observing an increase in aborted test runs halfway through the suite. However, the runs are aborted at different points, so it's not the same test case that causes this.

The error message in the test run log reads:

> Unexpected error occurred.  Aborting run: The start date 6/27/2013
>   10:28:38 AM cannot occur after the end date 6/27/2013 10:28:37 AM.

Sometimes the times are identical, sometimes they are a second off as quoted above.

Both involved machines (build server/test controller,  lab) are VMs. Both receive their system time via NTP from the same domain controller.

So I'm not sure if this really is a time issue, or if the error message is misleading. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot further? What other logs to consult?

Comment: Are the times in sync though? Is the NTP working as expected? Are all tiers of your TFS setup in Sync, SQL, App, etc?

Comment: The times of test controller and lab are in sync. I hadn't thought of checking all other tiers yet, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it IS a problem with massive clock drift. So basically the real question is about w32tm in a Hyper-V virtualised environment. We're experimenting with different settings now.