# TFS lab - Aborting run: The start date cannot occur after the end date

Tags: telerik

Recently we are working on integrate telerik test case into TFS 2012 BDT workflow.

But when there is failed test in test plan, all test case followed failed test case will be aborted with following error:

```
"ID"        "Date and time" "Message"
23           "09/23/2014 15:50:34"   "Error saving the test results: The start date 2014/9/23 15:50:05 cannot occur after the end date 2014/9/23 7:50:34. 
Will retry 3 time(s)."
24           "09/23/2014 15:51:05"   "Error saving the test results: The start date 2014/9/23 15:50:05 cannot occur after the end date 2014/9/23 7:50:34. 
Will retry 2 time(s)."
25           "09/23/2014 15:51:36"   "Error saving the test results: The start date 2014/9/23 15:50:05 cannot occur after the end date 2014/9/23 7:50:34. 
Will retry 1 time(s)."
26           "09/23/2014 15:52:06"   "Error saving the test results: The start date 2014/9/23 15:50:05 cannot occur after the end date 2014/9/23 7:50:34. 
Will retry 0 time(s)."
27           "09/23/2014 15:52:06"   "Unexpected error occurred.  Aborting run: The start date 2014/9/23 15:50:05 cannot occur after the end date 2014/9/23 7:50:34."
```

If all test cases pass, the issue will not occur.
If we run MSTest UI test even test case failed, no such issue will occur.

TFS version: 2012 RTM.
All TFS Lab are hyper-v VM.
Test controller, build controller are hyper-v VM.

All Build controller, test controller, test agent VM have China Beijing TimeZone setting.

We have tried to change timezone settings to UTC on Test controller, build controller, test agent VM, but the issue still exist.

Also we have checked Host server have china beijing timezone. TFS infrastructure are in domain of company. And time is correctly synced.

Some similar error in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342039/tfs-lab-test-run-aborted-the-start-date-cannot-occur-after-the-end-date), but we don't have any clue to fix it. Because all time are correctly synced.

Comment: Try to check and run the latest update for your environment and make sure they are the same, I can smell incompatible updates versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks M.Radwan.

We find out that our test agent is 2012 Update 4. But test controller is 2012.

After upgrade test controller to 2012 Update 4, the error is gone.